# Remove an entire word if it containins a word

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove entire word if the word contains specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894441/remove-entire-word-if-the-word-contains-specific-string)

How I can remove an entire word that contains a word?
For example, 'releas' should delete released, releases releasing etc.

```
/* Read in from the file here, not in the function - you only need to read the file once */
$wordlist = array('release','announce');

/* Sample data */
$words = 'adobe releases releases Acrobat X';

foreach ($wordlist as $v)
      $words = clean($v,$words);

function clean($wordlist,$value)
{
        return preg_replace("/\b$wordlist\b/i", '***',trim($value));
}  

echo 'Words: '.$words.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through your `$wordlist`

```
function clean($wordlist,$value)
{
    foreach ($wordlist as $word) {
        $value = preg_replace("/\b\w*$word\w*\b/i", '***', trim($value));
    }

    return $value;
}
```

and doing it in one replace

```
function clean($wordlist,$value)
{
    $all_words = implode('|', $wordlist);
    return preg_replace("/\b\w*(?:$all_words)\w*\b/i", '***', trim($value));
}
```

*Update*:

Looking through other answers and comments, it seems I haven't looked properly at the question. If `$wordlist` is *not* an array, you can just use @fthiella's answer.

Comment: @AD7six Escaping \ doesn't change anything in this case. Putting `$wordlist` into the pattern, does change the meaning although.

Comment: @AD7six Agreed and thank you for the explanation, I'm still learning PHP. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just a small confusion... the second approach - doing it all in one replace- can be used alone right? No need of the looping etc. right?

Comment: @Norman Sorry for being unclear, I fixed the answer.

Comment: @Norman Updated answer again.

Comment: Wordlist is an array. See my question. All words are put into that array.

Comment: @OlafDietsche in the original code `$wordlist` is an array, but it's also redefined inside the function `clean` where it's just a variable since there's a `foreach` already, outside the clean function. But I believe it's better to move the foreach inside, so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this REGEXP;

```
return preg_replace("/\w*$wordlist\w*/i", '***', trim($value));
```

Applyed to your code, it would be:

```
foreach ($wordlist as $v)
  $words = clean($v, $words);

function clean($word, $value) {
    return preg_replace("/\w*$word\w*/i", '***',trim($value));
}
```

(notice that I renamed `$wordlist` to `$word` to make things clearer, since `$wordlist` is also the name of the array)

Comment: I would have used `\w*$wordlist\w*` as \w implies the boudary \b

Comment: @AD7six $wordlist is not an array in the question, because it's redefined inside a function. There might be better solution, but code will work.

Comment: @Eineki you're right, thanks, \b is redundant since there's \w* already

Comment: @fthiella sorry - there are misleading variable names in the question

Comment: @AD7six no problem, it wasn't clear from the question, but I edited my answer to make it more evident, anyway I think that Olaf's approach is better in this situation!

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
$_words = implode( '|', $wordlist );

return preg_replace( "/\b\w*{$_words}\w*\b/i", "***", trim( $value ) );
```

or better

```
$_words = array();
foreach ( $wordlist as $word ) {
    $_words[] = '/\b\w*' . preg_quote( $word ) . '\w*\b/i';
}

return preg_replace( $_words, '***', trim( $value ) );
```

the second way avoids problems with regex, if some reserved chars appear inside the words.